# ¿Cómo puedo crear un CSV con unos datos que voy recogiendo?

Tags: python, csv

He conseguido a través de Python es abrir una carpeta que contiene imágenes pydcom con extensión .dcm.

Lo que tengo es: una vez leídas las carpetas necesito leer sus nombres pero no todas mis imágenes tienen nombre. Por tanto, lo que he hecho es esto:

```
import glob
import pydicom

for file in glob.glob("C:/Users/desco/Desktop/ImagenesDICOM/*.dcm"):
ds = pydicom.dcmread(file)
name=ds.PatientName
if (name=="Fall 1" or name=="Fall 2" or name=="Fall 3" or name=="Fall 4" or name=="Fall 5" or  name=="Fall 7"):
    print("nombre no encontrado")

else:
    print(name)
```

la salida que me da es la siguiente:

```
Carlos
pepe
Juan
nombre no encontrado
nombre no encontrado
nombre no encontrado
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que genere un csv que incluya nombre del fichero,
descripción del estudio y fecha de la imagen? Comprueba que es correcto.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la salida que querrías tener? ¿La duda concreta es cómo crear el csv? Revisa la librería `csv` de Python, en concreto [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

Comment: no, lo que pretendo es que leea una carpeta que contenga todas las imágenes y me genere un csv con todos los nombres de los pacientes que se encuentra en las imágenes.dcm

Comment: sí, esa parte la entiendo. Pero el resultado final que quieres es un csv, ¿sí? ¿En qué formato? ¿Deben aparecer los de "no encontrado"?

Comment: En el formado de: nombre: nombre 1, nombre 2.                                                 Lo de no lo he encontrado creo que estaría mal (eso lo puse por probar) , porque si el archivo .dcm no tiene nombre, no lo pondrá.

Comment: Por cierto lo de `if (name=="Fall 1" or name=="Fall 2" or name=="Fall 3" or name=="Fall 4" or name=="Fall 5" or  name=="Fall 7")` podría reducirse a `if name in ["Fall 1", "Fall 2", ... "Fall 7"]`.